# coordinates in document space after scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I want to place a div in an exact location on the page after some elements on the page are clicked on.

I do this via d3.js

For that, I use

```
// this gets executed when clicking on an element
let p = svg.createSVGPoint();
p.x = 0;
p.y = event_desc_pos_y;
let pt = p.matrixTransform(p.getScreenCTM());
let event_desc_div = d3.select('#event_description_div')
                            .style('top', pt.y + 'px')
                            .style('left', pt.x + 'px')
                            .style('width', width + 'px');
```

where I also have

```
#event_description_div {
  position:absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left:50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100px;
}
```

however, when I have scrolled down the page, this code seems to position this div wildly out of place (meaning, not on the same location relative to the absolute top of the page)

I'm not sure what it is doing since it doesn't look like it places it within the page in absolute terms but also not even relatively on the viewed page (the position goes up in the page as I scroll down)

`pt.y` and `pl.x` do not change.

In any case, it doesn't work. The placement depends heavily on the scrolling.

How can I place the div always in the exact same place regardless of whether the page has been scrolled or not?

Comment: By 'place' in the page do you mean it is to be between two known elements, or are you talking about the viewport and you want it 'sticking' to a definite place in the viewport?

Comment: I meant the first one. Placing it so that, relative to the absolute top of the page, the div is always on the same position regardless of whether we have scrolled before the placing takes place.

Comment: If you want a div to be positioned relative to the top of the page why not just put it as the first element after body (or prepend it to body if you are creating it on the fly) and position it absolute? I don't understand why it would have anything to do with the actual screen or the scrolling situation. Have I misunderstood the requirement?

Comment: The div gets placed dynamically upon interacting with the page. If some elements are clicked on, I want a div placed at a certain place displaying text related to the thing it was clicked.

To that end, I insert a div upon clicking and specify the coordinates where it should go. 

The placing goes horribly badly whenever the clicking (that triggers the div insertion) has been done after some scrolling.

Comment: Why do it by coordinates as opposed to putting it in (appending it directly after, say) the element in the DOM at the place you want it to be seen?

Comment: the div goes on top of an existing svg, I want this svg to have some visual elements but also a scrollable paragraph of text. Looking around, it seems like this is difficult to do directly with svg (the text part) so what I want to do is to place the div exactly within the rest of the other visual elements, responsible for hosting the paragraph, where scrolling is then easy to accomplish.